# Why are the controls in my new WPF window frozen?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

So I'm dealing with problem on my WPF app. I need to call popup window with few controls (textboxes, buttons).

So i created new window:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Ultra_Script_WPF.User_Settings.AppPasswordWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ultra_Script_WPF.User_Settings"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AppPasswordWindow" Height="229.5" Width="360" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="False" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <Label Content="Old Password: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="86"/>
        <Label Content="New Password: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="86"/>
        <Label Content="Confirm Password: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="107"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="144,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="144,51,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="144,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And i call my window like this:

```cs
AppPasswordWindow apppasswordwindow = new AppPasswordWindow();
apppasswordwindow.Show();
```

Problem is every control is frozen in that window. I cant write into textboxes or click buttons. I can resize the window i can close it.

PS: Main window in behind is still working fine.

Any suggestions what could cause this?

Comment: Is anything else blocking the UI you know of; for example: where you are calling the code to construct a new instance? Could  you also show the code inside `AppPasswordWindow`? You're also missing an ending tag as well: `</Window>`, maybe a type-o?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ im calling new window from button on usercontrol. There is nothing in apppassword just InitializeComponent(); And tag missing is just bad copy (edited) I cant even write into textboxes on my new window.

Comment: Hi Johyn. I notice you have a bunch of large margins in your markup. This is OK if you know the exact setup of all machines your app will be delivered to. Because you usually can't it's widely considered bad practice for commercial apps. My advice would be to use rows and columns to give proportional spacing in your grid. Never drag drop a control onto the design surface - work in the xaml by typing in your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `IsHitTestVisible="False"` attribute in your `AppPasswordWindow`. It prevents hit testing and thus prevents the framework from detecting mouse events.

Comment: Thank you! Had no idea how it got there. Maybe missclick. But still had no idea what it does. Thank you :D